# Relative Path functions.php Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am adding a little woo hook in a child theme, to echo a free shipping banner, having problem with the path to image, which is next to the functions.php file in the theme root.

```
    function denzilla_add_below_prod_meta() {
   echo '<div class="free-shipping" style="background: #fdfd5a; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 15px">';
   echo 'img src="free.jpg" />';
   echo '</div>';
}
```

is the function, but am just getting the text "img src="free.jpg" />"  output on front end page instead of the actual image.

Any tips on the correct path (both files are next to each other in theme root) or maybe one of the get_theme_url or similar hooks to do it?

[image: text front end]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with these 2 things

1. Your img tag looks broken, so please update it like echo '';
2. Use get_template_directory_uri() to get the image path

Comment: Yes img tag was not opened, tried this function denzilla_add_below_prod_meta() {
   echo '<div class="free-shipping" style="background: #fdfd5a; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 15px">';
   echo get_template_directory_uri()."/img/free.jpg">;
   echo '</div>';
}
but still something missing, img src looks like?  Not done php wp for a while.

Comment: It should be something like 
function denzilla_add_below_prod_meta() {
 echo '<div class="free-shipping" style="background: #fdfd5a; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 15px">'; 

echo '<img src="'".get_template_directory_uri()."'/img/free.jpg" />'; 
echo '</div>'; 
}

Comment: OK will check and get back Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function denzilla_add_below_prod_meta() {
    echo '<div class="free-shipping" style="background: #fdfd5a; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 15px">';
    echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/free.jpg" />';
    echo '</div>';
  }
  add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'denzilla_add_below_prod_meta', 25);
  
?>
```

Comment: This is close but not quite, seems tricky this, functions.php is in the root folder, img folder, with free.jpg inside it, is in same root folder. But I just get the yellow placeholder background, and the typical empty image display. Tricky!